# Is there a way to make the same app available through both VPP and the general App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

The scenario is the following:

Company A has an app that I'm customizing for company B. 
Company B would like to initially keep the app private within Company B and authorized resellers of Company B's products. 
In the future, Company B may want to make the app available to the general public in the public App Store.

It seems that the 'Custom B2B' app option is the right option as a developer and then distribute the app through the VPP to Company B, but I'm not clear on what I have to do to make the App also available in the general App Store when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the VPP flag in iTunes Connect afterwards and then it will be publicly available. Not only for registered VPP customers. (And VPP is still possible, since every app in the appstore may be purchased via the VPP).

Section: **Rights and Pricing**
There is a checkbox called **Custom B2B App**.

Quoting the info Text:

> An app that is set up as a custom B2B app will only be available to
>   the Volume Purchase Program customers that you specify in iTunes
>   Connect, and it will only be available in the applicable territories
>   (for example, U.S. Volume Purchase Program customers must use the U.S.
>   App Store Volume Purchase Program for Business). Custom B2B apps will
>   not be available to educational institutions or general App Store
>   customers. To learn more about the App Store Volume Purchase Program
>   for Business, visit http://vpp.itunes.apple.com/faq. To learn more
>   about how your customers can sign up for the Volume Purchase Program,
>   visit http://enroll.vpp.itunes.apple.com.

Comment: Where can I find this flag?

Comment: The VPP flag is not changeable after you have initially set up the app.  "Note that the Custom B2B App option will only be available when setting up the first version of your app, and only when the first version is in an editable state."  From  https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq, and also from experience.